# Android app widget SeekBar progress survives onDestroy()

Tags: android, rotation, widget, seekbar, ondestroy

I have started studying Android programming recently after taking a very long break (half a decade) from programming altogether. It's been going well so far.

I have noticed that Seek Bar's progress survives onDestroy event after a rotation (configuration change) happens and this happened on a fragmented activity. Then I created an empty activity and added the widget in the layout and the result is the same (as I expected but still tried due to some code). I also tried overriding the onCreate method and passing a null SavedBundleInstance into super.onCreate() and the result is the same. So I don't know where the Seek Bar's progress location is saved before onDestroy and then passed back unless I am missing some static variable in the SeekBar class or its super classes. (I just thought about that now, I should check it)

Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: I just created an empty activity and added a Seek Bar widget in the default layout. That's all. I am sorry, I thought that was obvious in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, Android `View`s save their state upon rotation. The same happens for example with `EditText`. If you input something and then rotate the device, the text will be kept.
It's done inside the specific `View` class.

But how is this state persisted through orientation changes?
In Activities, for example, you have `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)`. That method is called by the system before a configuration change occurs. What you do, to persist the state of the `Activity`, is to store inside `bundle` the values you want to save. Then, when the `Activity` is created again, this `bundle` is passed back to you, for example in the `onCreate` method. This way you can restore your state.

But what about `View`s? They use a similar mechanism. If we want the details we have to look at the source code. Let's look at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java) of `ProgressBar`. It turns out that the `View` has a `onSaveInstanceState`, too ([this line](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java#1930)). You can see there, that the progress is being saved.

I hope this clarifies the mechanism.

Comment: Thank you, I realize that, but I am looking for a more thorough explanation. More in depth if you will. It's probably some static object keeping these values and I can't yet get on the computer to look but I couldn't find any information on why the can survive onDestroy on rotation vs die on onDestroy when the app closes (isFinishing() = true).

Comment: I came home and did more digging. The view by default saves its state. The derived class ProgressBar as you said saves its state by first calling super.onSaveInstanceState() and then saving its progress etc. In the end saveHierarchyState() calls dispatchSaveInstanceState() to init and finish the whole process (I think). By the way, you can enable/disable saving of a View object by calling its setSaveEnabled(boolean) method. I have tried and it works. I'll have more digging into these Android OS files with more given time.